# Macro task vs micro task

Tags: javascript

why the event loop prioritizes cartoon's setTimeouts than the **then's** setTimeout? what I know is, the event loop should prioritize the micro task such as promises, then executes the message queue(cartoon's setTimeouts).

```js
const tom = () => console.log('Tom');
const jerry = () => console.log('Jerry');
const doggy = () => console.log('Doggy');
const cartoon = () => {
    console.log('Cartoon');
    setTimeout(tom, 0);
    setTimeout(doggy, 0);
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('I am a Promise, right after tom and doggy! Really?');
    }).then(resolve => {
        console.log(resolve);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('inner timeout')
        }, 0)
    });
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        resolve('I am a Promise after Promise!')
    ).then(resolve => console.log(resolve));
    jerry();
}
cartoon();
```

**Output:**

```
"Cartoon"
"Jerry"
"I am a Promise, right after tom and doggy! Really?"
"I am a Promise after Promise!"
"Tom"
"Doggy"
"inner timeout"
```

Comment: The `.then()`s just add to the microtask queue. Your microtask is then to add a macro task. But there are already two macro tasks added (`tom` and `jerry`). It's a *queue*, so your task to print `'inner timeout'` would be be *behind them*.

Answer (score 5):

**Caveat:** Don't make assumptions about promise timing (other than that fulfillment/rejection handlers will not be called synchronously, which isn't an assumption, it's a guarantee genuine promises provide). It's fine to do this sort of thing to explore what happens, as a learning exercise, but don't make code rely on the interaction between tasks and microtasks. :-)

> why the event loop prioritizes `cartoon`'s `setTimeouts` than the `then`'s `setTimeout`?

Because they were scheduled earlier.

> what I know is, the event loop should prioritize the micro task such as promises, then executes the message queue(cartoon's setTimeouts).

Which is consistent with the results you're getting. The two calls to `setTimeout` at the top level of `cartoon` happen immediately. The call to `setTimeout` from the promise fulfillment handler doesn't happen until after those have already run. It's when they're **scheduled** that sets the order in which they're later executed (since they all have the same timeout value). (It doesn't matter that the `setTimeout` is in a fulfillment handler, even if you called `setTimeout` where you created the promise, you'd still be calling it after the other two, so it would be scheduled for after the other two.)

(Side note: `Promise.resolve(x)` is equivalent to `new Promise(resolve => resolve(x))` and easier to type. :-) )

See further explanation in comments:

```js
const tom = () => console.log('Tom');
const jerry = () => console.log('Jerry');
const doggy = () => console.log('Doggy');
const cartoon = () => {
    console.log('Cartoon');
    // ↓ Schedules the call to `tom`
    setTimeout(tom, 0);

    // ↓ Schedules the call to `doggy`; it was scheduled later with the same
    // ↓ timeout value, so it will happen after the call to `tom`
    setTimeout(doggy, 0);

    // ↓ Creates a new promise which is immediately fulfilled
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('I am a Promise, right after tom and doggy! Really?');
    })
    // ↓ Attaches a fulfillment handler to that promise
    .then(resolve => {
        // This handler won't be called until the microtasks queued by the
        // task in which the promise was fulfilled are run

        console.log(resolve);

        // ↓ Schedules the call showing 'inner timeout', which will occur
        // ↓ after the calls to `tom` and `doggy` because it was scheduled
        // ↓ later (it would be even if it weren't in a promise fulfillment
        // ↓ handler, just like `doggy` is called after `tom`)
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('inner timeout')
        }, 0)
    });

    // ↓ Creates a new promise which is immediately fulfilled
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        resolve('I am a Promise after Promise!')
    )
    // ↓ Attaches a fulfillment handler to that promise
    .then(resolve => {
        // This handler won't be called until the microtasks queued by the
        // task in which the promise was fulfilled are run

        console.log(resolve);
    });

    // ↓ Calls `jerry` right away, before any microtasks or other tasks scheduled by
    // this task could possibly run
    jerry();
}
cartoon();
```

To see task vs. microtask scheduling in action, here's an example (but see the caveat above):

```js
const task = () => console.log("task");
const microtask1 = () => console.log("microtask1");
const fulfillment1 = () => console.log("fulfillment1 (microtask2)");
const microtask3 = () => console.log("microtask3");
const fulfillment2 = () => console.log("fulfillment2 (microtask4)");

setTimeout(task, 0);
queueMicrotask(microtask1);
Promise.resolve("hi")
.then(fulfillment1)
.then(fulfillment2);
queueMicrotask(microtask3);

// Output:
//
// microtask1
// fulfillment1 (microtask2)
// microtask3
// fulfillment2 (microtask4)
// task
```

When the JavaScript engine is given that code, it:

1. Runs the task to execute that code

   1. Schedules `task` for "as soon as possible" in the task queue
      *(some handwaving here, but that's accurate for the above; `setTimeout(fn, 0)` doesn't* always *schedule for ASAP, though, if nested a brief delay may be added)*
   2. Queues a microtask (`microtask1`)
   3. Queues another microtask (`fulfillment1) (because` then` was called on a fulfilled promise)
   4. Queues a third microtask (`microtask3`)
2. Reaches the end of that task, and processes the microtask queue

   1. Runs `microtask1`
   2. Runs `fulfillment1`

      - Doing that fulfills the promise created by the first call to `then`, which queues `fulfillment2` as a microtask
   3. Runs `microtask3`
   4. Runs `fulfillment2` because it was queued by #2.2 above
3. Reachs the end of the microtask queue
4. Runs the next available task

   1. Calls `task`

Even though `task` was scheduled before any of the microtasks, it ran after them, even the one that wasn't scheduled until *during* the processing of the microtask queue.

But again, while useful for learning purposes, remember that the exact sequence above relies on exactly when the promises are fulfilled. In real world code, you have a promise because you have an asynchronous operation that may take *N* time, so you don't know when it will be fulfilled, so you can't make assumptions about when its reactions will be run.

Answer (score 2):

When you schedule a micro-task that contains the `setTimeout` call, that micro-task will schedule another macro-task which will be added at the end of the macro-task queue.

As queue is FIFO (first in first out), tasks scheduled earlier are processed before the task scheduled using the micro-task.

In your case, tasks scheduled using the following `setTimeout` calls

```
setTimeout(tom, 0);
setTimeout(doggy, 0);
```

were scheduled earlier, so they are processed before the task scheduled using the micro-task.

> what I know is, the event loop should prioritize the micro task such
> as promises, then executes the message queue(cartoon's setTimeouts).

it is prioritized.

A microtask queue is processed:

- after each callback as long as the call-stack is empty
- after each task

So after your script has ended, micro-task queue will be processed until all the micro-tasks have been processed. In your case, first micro-task will schedule a macro-task in the macro-task queue.

At this point, macro-task and the micro-tasks look like this:

```
macro-tasks = [
    () => console.log('Tom'), 
    () => console.log('Doggy'), 
    () => console.log('inner timeout')
]

micro-tasks = []
```

and the console output up to this point is:

```
Cartoon
Jerry    
I am a Promise, right after tom and doggy! Really?   
I am a Promise after Promise!
```

After micro-task queue has bee processed, next macro-task from the macro-task queue will be processed which is

```
() => console.log('Tom')
```

and the task scheduled by the micro-task

```
() => console.log('inner timeout')`
```

will be processed at the end.